# Can I run py2app on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, py2app

I recently discovered that an outdated version of Python was causing my Wx app to run into errors.

I can't install Python 2.7.3 on my Mac, and when I tried it in a virtual machine, py2app was still "compiling" the app after running overnight (my Windows/Linux box has an ≈1GHz processor).

Is there a version of py2app that runs on Windows?

Comment: are you looking for py2exe? http://www.py2exe.org/

Comment: @tehmisvh No, I'd like to build mac .app bundles on Windows

Comment: I'm also looking for some way to make .app bundles on a windows computer, but it sounds like that's not possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [project page](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2app/) and the [readme](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/README.txt), py2app is directed at creating Mac apps out of python code. Obviously you won't be able to run the final product on a windows machine. But if the question is can you build the app on windows and run it on a mac, then the answer is still no, because if you go to the [setup.py](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/setup.py), it says `'Operating System :: MacOS :: MacOS X'` and there are no forks for windows because it depends on some Mac SDK tools like `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk`. Looks like you are out of luck. If you are desperate, try [Virtual box](https://www.virtualbox.org/) to emulate a mac on your windows machine, or be content with a windows build with py2exe

Comment: I discovered virtual Python environments, so that takes care of 2.7.3 on Mac. However, I don't even have a /Developer folder, and py2app runs fine, which is odd. Thanks for the answer, though. It's weird that nobody has ported it to Windows.

Answer (score 0):

No, There's no way on earth you can run py2app on windows,py2app cannot create a Mac app bundle in windows because it's impossible to do so... Either hackintosh your pc or emulate a mac using QEMU,VMware or VirtualBox!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).